# Text on website created with Next.js has bigger size on iPhone/iPad than on other devices

Tags: iphone, next.js

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days already and no matter what I try, nothing works.

On my android phone and PC my website looks like this:

[image: website on android]

But on iPhones and iPads the text size is bigger and causes unwanted changes in styling:

[image: website iPhone]

As you can see, because the text is bigger, in some of the components the text goes outside of the circle, which obviously I don't want.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this before I go crazy?

I have used next.js to create the app and styled-components for all the styling.

My  tag in the _document.js file looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

I have used Meyer CSS Reset in the globals.js file.

I would really appreciate any help, as I have no idea what more I can do...

Thanks.

Edit: For more context, I don't think it's a Next.j issue, most likely it has to do with css.

This is the CSS code in globals.js (I am using styled-components for styling) where I use font-size:

```
body {
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary};
  font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  background: linear-gradient(199deg, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 0%, 
  rgba(233, 233, 233, 1) 50%, rgba(214, 214, 214, 1) 100%);
  cursor: default;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,button {
  font-family: "Great-Vibes", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  line-height: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.headings}
}
```

Comment: are you certain this is a Next.js issue and not a css issue? Can you provide the css used by the text?

Comment: I don't think it's a Next.js issue, I provided that info for context.

This is the CSS in the globals.js file where I used font-size:

    body {
      color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary};
      font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      background: linear-gradient(199deg, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(233, 233, 
      233, 1) 50%, rgba(214, 214, 214, 1) 100%);
      cursor: default;
      transition: 0.5s ease;
      padding: 100px 0 0 0;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

Comment: h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,button {
      font-family: "Great-Vibes", sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
      line-height: 2rem;
      font-size: 2rem;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.headings}
    }

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76634839/edit) your question and provide the relevant code

Comment: Since you are using `rem` for your font sizes, is it possible the iOS device you are testing on has a setting increasing the root font size thereby increasing your relative font size? Try using `px` instead of `rem` and see if the font size stays the same across all devices

Comment: I was thinking about this as well, but that's not how you build responsive web sites though, so I was hoping I might get other ideas... 

I will try it out though, just to test if the issue is related to this.

Comment: Why is that not how you build responsive websites? If you're using `rem` you are accepting that the client may change root font size. You can absolutely use `px` in responsive websites!!! If you use `rem` you inherently accept that it may change depending on the client, thus, if you do **not intend that** then don't use `rem`, use another unit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, as you noticed I am not quite the expert, I just finished a web development bootcamp and the coaches always said "don't use px for responsive websites". Now I understand much better, so thanks. However, changing the font size in the globals and in each component where I used font size didn't solve the issue, on iPhones the text is still much bigger than other devices...